# Django testing function that sets external managed database autocommit to True

Tags: python, django

Say I have this function I want to test

```py
from django.db import connections

def to_be_tested(...):
    connections['external'].set_autocommit(True)
    ....
```

and in my transactionised test case

```py
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        to_be_tested(...)
        ...
```

This causes django to complain

```
  File "/Users/jlin/projects/service/api/views/serviceorder.py", line 100, in post
    connections['external'].set_autocommit(True)
  File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 404, in set_autocommit
    self.validate_no_atomic_block()
  File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 443, in validate_no_atomic_block
    "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.")
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

How do I get Django unittest to ignore this since it's not a `default` database?

My current workaround is lying about it and it seems work fine when `to_be_tested(...)` doesn't cause an error to roll back.

```py
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        connections['external'].in_atomic_block = False
        to_be_tested(...)
        connections['external'].in_atomic_block = True
        ...
```